# TabItem headers: Content doesn't stretch if the actual tab header does

Tags: wpf

I have a TabControl and am attempting to get the headers to look nice. I have the following XAML:

(In `Resources.xaml`:)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ClosableTabItemTemplate">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" MinWidth="200" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" behaviors:MouseClickBehavior.ClickCommand="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}">
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <Button Background="Transparent"
                  BorderBrush="Transparent"
                  Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"
                  Content="X"
                  Cursor="Hand"
                  DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                  Focusable="False" 
                  FontSize="9"
                  FontWeight="Bold"
                  Margin="3,0,0,0"
                  Padding="0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                  Width="16" Height="16" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

(In `MainWindow.xaml`:)

```
<TabControl Grid.Column="1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tabs}"
            ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}" />
```

Here is a visual example of my problem:

[image]

I like the actual width of the tabs for now, but the fact that my dockpanel for the header isn't filling up all the space is bothersome. Same thing happens if I use a `Grid`, too (presumably any container control).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try overwritting the `ItemContainerStyle.Template` instead of the `ContentTemplate`

I did something like this in the past, although I overwrote the entire `TabControl` template so it's a bit hard to see what I was doing. My code looked like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CurvedTabItemTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <DockPanel Width="200">
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="CurvedTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CurvedTabItemTemplate}" />
</Style>

<TabControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tabs}" 
            ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource CurvedTabItemStyle}" />
```

Comment: This gave me some bizarre behavior where the tabs' inner content and the tab headers were flipped... gonna keep trying different things though...

Comment: Got it. Turns out I was actually looking at the wrong file entirely.

Answer (score 8):

`ContentPresenter.HorizontalAlignment` in the default style for `TabItem` is bound to `ItemsControl.HorizontalContentAlignment`. Here it is, taken from Aero.NormalColor.xaml:

```
<ContentPresenter Name="Content"
                  ContentSource="Header"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="{Binding Path=HorizontalContentAlignment,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                  VerticalAlignment="{Binding Path=VerticalContentAlignment,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
                  RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
```

Setting `TabControl.HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch` fixes the issue for me.

```
<TabControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Comment: Great! This is a lot easier than the other solutions.

Comment: Great one liner, so obvious I should have seen it.

Comment: Great and simple answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same visual issue with closable tabs and resolved it by extending both the `TabControl` (to be used later in XAML) and `TabItem` classes. I overrode `GetContainerForItemOverride()` in the former, and `OnApplyTemplate()` in the latter. I created a `DependencyObject` extension method to find the `ContentPresenter` element of the `TabItem` and set its `HorizontalAlignment` property to `HorizontalAlignment.Stretch`:

```
public class MyTabControl : TabControl
{
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        return new MyTabItem();
    }
}

public class MyTabItem : TabItem
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var content = this.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ContentPresenter>();
        if (content != null)
        {
            content.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        }
    }
}

public static class DependencyObjectExtensions
{
    public static T GetFirstDescendantOfType<T>(this DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (parent == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            var children = parent.GetChildren();
            T descendant = children.FirstOrDefault(child => child is T) as T;

            if (descendant == null)
            {
                foreach (var child in children)
                {
                    if ((descendant = child.GetFirstDescendantOfType<T>()) != null) break;
                }
            }

            return descendant;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetChildren(this DependencyObject parent)
    {
        var children = new List<DependencyObject>();

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
        {
            children.Add(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i));
        }

        return children;
    }
}
```

My XAML appears as the following:

(In `MainWindowResources.xaml`):

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ClosableTabItemTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=CloseCommand}"
                Content="X"
                Cursor="Hand"
                DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                Focusable="False"
                FontFamily="Courier"
                FontSize="9"
                FontWeight="Bold"
                Margin="8,1,0,0"
                Padding="0"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
                Width="16"
                Height="16"
                ToolTip="Close" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

(In `MainWindow.xaml`): **Note the use of the custom `MyTabControl` control**

```
<MyTabControl IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ClosableViewModels}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
              Margin="4" />
```

Comment: I love you! I have been looking for 2 hours trying to get my custom TabHeader UserControl to fill/stretch the width of the Tab. Your ControlHelper and OnApplyTemplate() has solved my problem.